# How to combine this two LINQ Query in a single var result

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my code. I would like to combine this 2 LINQ Query in a single var result. I use these techniques:

```
var result = queryOne.Union(queryTwo);
var result = queryOne.Concat(queryTwo);
var result = Enumerable.Union(queryOne, queryTwo);
```

This doesn't work. How to do this right? I am newly in LINQ and C#.

```
var queryOne = await (from x in _context.DwPropertyMasters
                                  where
                                  x.LandId == 2
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      x.LandId,
                                      x.MapPointX,
                                      x.MapPointY,
                                      x.Location,
                                      a = x.Development == null || x.Development == "" ? x.Location : x.Development,
                                      AreaSize = x.AreaSize ?? 0,
                                      Premium = x.Premium ?? 0,
                                      b = (((x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000) / (x.AreaSize == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize)) ?? 0,
                                      x.Developer,
                                      x.YearTender,
                                      c = x.Development ?? x.Location,
                                      AreaSize2 = x.AreaSize2 ?? 0,
                                      d = (((x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000) / (x.AreaSize2 == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize2)) ?? 0,
                                  }).ToArrayAsync();

            var queryTwo = await (from y in _context.DwPropertyDetails
                                  where
                                  y.LandId == 2
                                  orderby
                                  y.Block,
                                  y.Asp descending
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      y.LandDetailId,
                                      y.LandId,
                                      a = y.Pasp ?? "",
                                      b = y.Asp ?? "",
                                      c = y.Tasp ?? "",
                                      y.Block,
                                      y.Floor,
                                      y.Unit,
                                      d = y.CarParking ?? "",
                                      y.SalePrice,
                                      e = y.Revision ?? "",
                                      y.VendorRelate,
                                      y.TransactionPrice,
                                      y.FlatType,
                                      y.ActualSize,
                                      f =
                                      ((y.TransactionPrice == 0 ? null : y.TransactionPrice) / (y.ActualSize == 0 ? null : y.ActualSize)) ??
                                      0
                                  }).ToArrayAsync();

            var singleQuery = queryOne.Union(queryTwo);



 var result = queryOne.Union(queryTwo);
    var result = queryOne.Concat(queryTwo);
    var result = Enumerable.Union(queryOne, queryTwo);
```

This doesn't work. How to do this right? I am newly in LINQ and C#.

Comment: Yes, The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable<TSource> System.Linq.Enumerable.Union<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you checked individual queries for the result.

Comment: Yes, they have different properties and values.

Comment: Does it work without the await?

Answer (score 1):

Your first LINQ returns an enumerable of different objects than the second one, and there is no way you can concatenate those two. They have to return the same type of objects.

```
var query1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => new
    {
        Id = i,
        Ids = 0 // See, this object has more properties than the second query's object.
    });

var query2 = Enumerable.Range(11, 20)
    .Select(i => new
    {
        Id = i,
    });

query1.Concat(query2); // Won't compile!
```

You have to use the same number of properties for each in the same order and type, or you can define a custom class for that.

Comment: *each in the same order* AND type :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks context right now, but since the only reason why you wouldn't be able to concatinate 2 `IEnumerable<T>` is because they are of different type.

If you are using an anonymous type on 2 places that's a good time to make this anonymous type into it's own class, this way you should be able to `.Concat` the 2 results.

But again you can see some obvious differences in your 2 query types. Another option would be to create third type which accepts contains all of the members of the other 2 queries.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But is there another way to concat this two LINQ query? I don't know how to do.

Comment: I've added some more info @Fred

Comment: How to do that? Can you give me an example? Please?